# Add comma after value only if more than one value?

Tags: php

Im trying to echo a set of values for categories. What I'd like to do is if there are more than one value, append a comma afterwards. Here's a snippet of what I have:

```
<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { echo $category->cat_name . ', '; } ?>
```

The problem with this is that categories with one value will have a comma at the end.

Comment: You need to check whether your final string ends with a comma and then remove it. The problem will occur whether you have one item or more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Alternative 1

Add all values to an array and then just use [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to glue them all together:

```
$catArray = [];

foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
    $catArray[] = $category->cat_name; 
}

// Now we can implode the array, using , as the glue
echo implode(', ', $catArray);
```

#### Alternative 2

You could also prepend the commas in your loop so you don't need any if-statements:

```
$glue = '';

foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
    echo $glue . $category->cat_name; 
    $glue = ', ';
}
```

or a shorter version (not as readable though and requires PHP 7+):

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
    echo ($glue ?? '') . $category->cat_name; 
    $glue = ', ';
}
```

The first iteration won't get any comma in front of it, but the rest will.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the count of results from `get_the_category()`, set a counter and increment that each time through the loop. Check if `$i` is equal to the count and if it is, don't add the comma.

Assuming that function is countable and you don't need checks to make sure their aren't 0 results:

```
<?php
    $count = count(get_the_categories());
    $i = 1;
    foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
        if($i < $count) {
            echo $category->cat_name . ', '; 
        } else {
             echo $category->cat_name;
        }
        $i++;
    } 
?>
```